# Unexpected token d in json at positon 0 while doing it in angular2 .POST cal

Tags: json, angular

```
onCreateCategoryPostData() {
    let dat=JSON.stringify({"key":this.inputcat})
    alert(dat);
    this._http.CreateCategorypostData(dat)
        .subscribe(
        data => alert(dat),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("finished")
        );
}
```

Comment: What does `CreateCategorypostData` look like? What does `_http` look like?

Comment: problem solved ..wrote this in py service to get data " data1= request.body.read() "